# How to know if a function is a class or a function

Tags: javascript

I'm actually trying to differentiate (in my code) functions and classes.

I need to know, in a simple console.log, if the parameter of my function is a class or a simple function.

I'm actually taking about class, not object, but really a class.

Like:

```
function(item){
    if(isClass(item)){
        console.log('it s a class !');
    }else{
        if(isFunc(item)){
            console.log('it s a function !');
         }
    }
}
```

Edit : angular 2 is able to distinguish a function and a class in his injector container class

Comment: Define "*really a class.*"

Comment: There is no such conception called "Class" in JS. However, you can use `Function` and `Prototype` to simulate a "Class", still, it is actually a function.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any classes in JavaScript. Though functions can be instanciated with the `new` keyword.

You can check if something is a function with `instanceof`:

```
var a = function() {};

a instanceof Function; // true
```

An instanciated function will be an instance of that specific function:

```
var b = new a();

b instanceof Function; // false
b instanceof a; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **no classes*** in Javascript. Instead functions in JavaScript *can act* like constructors with the help of `new` keyword. ([constructor](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#constructors_vs_prototypes) pattern)

Objects in JavaScript directly inherit from other objects, hence we don't need classes. All we need is a way to create and extend objects.

You can use `jQuery.isFunction()` to check if the argument passed to `isFunction()` is a Javascript function object.

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/):

`jQuery.isFunction()`

> Description: Determine if the argument passed is a JavaScript function object.

**EDIT:**
As rightly pointed out by [user2867288](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2867288/user2867288), the statement that Javascript has no classes needs to be taken with a pinch of salt.

Read these articles for more information about the ECMAScript 6 standard:

- [ECMAScript 6 Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript)
- [Classes in ECMAScript 6](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html)

Comment: There actually are classes in Javascript, ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @user2867288, could you elaborate on your point or point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's new to the ECMAScript standard. Which means browser support will be severely lacking for now. http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html

Answer (score 1):

Constructors ("classes") are only functions. There's not much that differentiates them.

However, their usage is quite different. Classes do typically have methods and maybe even other properties on their **prototype**. And that's in fact how you can distinguish them.<sup>1</sup>
Bound functions and functions constructed using arrow notation (ES6) even don't have a prototype at all.

```
function isFunc(fn) {
    return typeof fn == "function" && (!fn.prototype || !Object.keys(fn.prototype).length);
}
```

<sub>1: not detecting atypical classes that don't make use of prototypical inheritance</sub>

Comment: This idea is used in the [Bluebird library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/634af0e27ff4faab62c6c5bfd105527abcf8b06e/src/util.js#L163).

Comment: So, there is no reliable way to distinguish between a class (though it is a function in disguise) and a function, right?

Comment: Yes, there is no reliable way. I'd say "*because* it is (disguised as) a function" :-)

Comment: Not even ES6 classes are - though there is discussion whether `Reflect.isCallable` should return `false` for them.

Comment: I was going through the spec to find if any of the internal slots which expose the actual type, but I couldn't :'(

Comment: @thefourtheye: Well, there's the `[[FunctionKind]]` internal slot which is set to `"classConstructor"` for "classes" (constructor functions created using the `class` keyword), but it is an *internal* slot (used only to throw errors on `[[Call]]`) :-)

Comment: Ya, but there is no function which can return that value. And `Reflect.isCallable` is not likely to land in ES6, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly - that's why I emphasized "internal". And while ES6 is basically settled, even for `isCallable` there was discussion whether it should not better return `true` because even when constructor throw on not being used with `new`, they do still have a `[[call]]` slot like every other callable thing.