# How can I differentiate between an arrow function, class and a normal function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

How can I differentiate between these three things in ES6 using its reference?

```
let x = i => i+1;

class y { constructor(i) { this._i=i+1; } get i(){ return this._i;} }

function z(i) { return i+1; }
```

Example:

```
test(x) //=> 'arrow'
test(y) //=> 'class'
test(z) //=> 'function'
```

And how can I differentiate between these things in transpilers - Traceur / Babel?

Comment: What is your usecase?
I would try to call func.toString() and see what i'm getting back and maybe analyse it.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that class names follow the long-standing tradition of constructors having uppercase first letter. That way it's easy to tell at a glance that `Function()` is either a class or constructor and `function()` is a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I differentiate between these things in ES6?

- arrow functions are functions that cannot be used as constructors, and don't have a `.prototype` property. However, methods don't either. They inherit from `Function.prototype`.
- classes are functions that can't be called without `new`, and that have a `.prototype` object which is normally not empty. If the `extends` keyword was used, they don't inherit from `Function.prototype`.
- functions are functions that can be called either way, and do have a `.prototype` that is [normally empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30547692/1048572). They inherit from `Function.prototype`.
- generator functions are functions that do have a `.prototype` which inherits from the intrinsic *GeneratorPrototype* object, and they inherit from the intrinsic *Generator* object.

As you can see, there are some clues. However, the properties and inheritance can always be messed with, so you cannot really trust it. Whether a function is a constructor (can be called with `new`) cannot be determined from outside, you have to call it and see whether it throws - which could be faked as well.

So your best bet might be `Function.prototype.toString`, to see how the source looked like. If your ES implementation supports that.

> And how can I differentiate between these things in transpilers?

I don't think any transpiler implements prototype-less arrows and methods. Whether a class constructor throws upon being called depends on the looseness of the transpilation, but that's not a good way for distinction anyway.
`toString` doesn't work either afaik.

Comment: Thanks!. I just tried it out on v8 and it works just fine. https://gist.github.com/boopathi/7c4adc4f4790f432838d . It fails when I try it on methods though.

Comment: Updated the gist. Now supports detecting generators and methods too. I hope my assumptions are correct. Mentioned them in code comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't the first two cases get transpiled into this:

```
var x = function x(i) {
  return i + 1;
};

function z(i) {
  return i + 1;
}
```

For the last one you could check if it complains if it's a class when you call it:

```
function isClass(instance){
  try{
    instance()
  }catch(e){
    return e.message === "Cannot call a class as a function";
  }
  return false;
}
```

But that will obviously trigger the side effects of calling it, so it doesn't work in the general case.

Comment: Err why did this get voted down? It directly answers the question. It's pretty rude to drive-by vote something down without explanation.

Comment: I think because you won't get transpiled until you use a transpiler, otherwise in native browsers that case will not be applied

Comment: @BarbuBarbu The last part of the question is specifically asking about differentiating after transpiling.

Comment: ooh, sure, sorry, my bad